# SQL: What is the fastest way to update Million records in a table (Only the ID column-values need to be updated)

Tags: mysql

My issue is with updating the current ID column (values) with new values in a table (The table has million of records).
It takes a long time till all records are updated.

The current query that I use is:
`update ZENDINGINHOUD_OLD set ID=ID+60780000`

Why the value `60780000`?
Because I have a second table `ZENDINGINHOUD_NEW` that has the max ID `60779999`, so I want to update the ID's on the table `ZENDINGINHOUD_OLD` to a higher ID.
After that, I want to insert all the records from `_OLD` into `_NEW`.

In the below statistic you can see that the "Clustrered  Index Update", " Table Spool" and "Collapse" exceed the 100% and that might be the issue why it takes a long time.  I just don't know how to efficient  adjust the query.
[Live Query Statistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wybQ7.png)

I hope someone can help me, I am new to this forum.

Comment: I would suggest to add technical details to make sure we can assist you

Comment: Can't you just add that value when you insert the records to the new table?

Comment: I think that `id` is primary index (and hence it is clustered index). If so then each row's update causes moving this row within the clustered index (deleteing on the old place and copying to new place) which is obviously slow (and produces many empty pages). In this case copying the data into new table with new `id` value and then replacing old table with new one will be faster.

Comment: I would suggest to reverse the procedure and add the offset to the data you are inserting from the other table. That way the overhead will vanish into the noise of the insert.